# How do you remove/edit the Dokan Store Tabs

Tags: php, wordpress, dokan

I am using Dokan for a listings site.  The core set of products that will be used are bookable products.

As such I want to rename the products field to 'Bookings'.  I have digging around in the plugin template files and can find where the tabs are included in the store template but can't seem to find where the actual tabs are defined.

Any help would be awesome thanks.  For reference below the code where the tabs are being included:

```
    <?php if ( $store_tabs ) { ?>
<div class="dokan-store-tabs<?php echo $no_banner_class_tabs; ?>">
    <ul class="dokan-list-inline">
        <?php foreach( $store_tabs as $key => $tab ) { ?>
            <li><a href="<?php echo esc_url( $tab['url'] ); ?>"><?php echo $tab['title']; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php do_action( 'dokan_after_store_tabs', $store_user->get_id() ); ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I am also having an issue with the reviews page (I removed the sidebars from store.php and store-review.php in child theme folder) and reviews page now just loads header and footer of my theme).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to figure out how to do it.

In the dokan plugin folder navigate to the includes folder.  Inside this folder there is a functions.php file.

Search for 'dokan_get_store_tabs('

Find and replace Products with text of your choice within this function.

Answer (score 1):

You can disable any tabs you want by adding a code in your function.php file (to avoid code deletion when theme updates).

*For example:*

**To remove the reviews tab**

```
// Disable Woocommerce Reviews Form Tab
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'wcs_woo_remove_reviews_tab', 98 );
    function wcs_woo_remove_reviews_tab($tabs) {
    unset($tabs['reviews']);
    return $tabs;
}
```

**And to remove extra tabs by calling tab name**

```
// Disable Seller More Products Tab
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'wcs_woo_remove_more_seller_product_tab', 98 );
    function wcs_woo_remove_more_seller_product_tab($tabs) {
    unset($tabs['more_seller_product']);
    return $tabs;
}
```

Hope this can help you :)

Answer (score 0):

for remove Seller info tab on product page in dokan plugin:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_tabs', 'dokan_remove_seller_info_tab', 50 );
function dokan_remove_seller_info_tab( $array ) {
unset( $array['seller'] );
return $array;
 }
```

for remove seller button on WC dashboard in dokan plugin:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_my_account', array( Dokan_Pro::init(), 'dokan_account_migration_button' ) );
```

for disable registration as a seller in WC registration in dokan plugin:

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_register_form', 'dokan_seller_reg_form_fields' );
```